# Triggering after before callbacks while using bulk_import in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, bulkinsert

I want to insert millions of data and don't have an option to hit the db that many times instead, using this [gem](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) to do bulk insertion, but as it said it is just doing the bulk insertion and doesn't have in-memory Activerecord object it can't run before and after save callbacks.

So, to do that I wrote a code to manually trigger the before_callback.

```
valid_books = []
invalid_books = []

books.each do |book|
  if book.valid?
    valid_books << book
  else
    invalid_books << book
  end
end

valid_books.each do |book|
  book.run_callbacks(:save) { false }
  book.run_callbacks(:create) { false }
end

Book.import valid_books, validate: false
```

Referred from gem documentation itself. Now how do I run after callbacks, after importing the data. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`bulk_import` is not helpful when we have `before` and `after` callbacks.

Either you will have to invoke after_callbacks for each inserted record or go with `.create` which would accept bulk data.

```
Ex: Model.create({{...}, {...}, {...} ...})
```

I suggest you to create records in background jobs:

**Job1**

1. Setup an `ActiveJob` for `batch_import`
2. Parse data as JSON. Ex - `data_hash: {{...}, {...}, {...} ...}`
3. Split data in batches and loop through each batch
4. Call `Job2(batch_data)`

**Job2**

1. Setup an `ActiveJob` for `batch_create` purpose
2. Have a `DB.Transaction` block
3. Do `Model.create(batch_data)`
4. Wrap above steps within `begin..rescue..ensure` block

**With that**:

- You will have the `validations` & `callbacks` being invoked as expected
- Have multiple workers complete the task of creating records in background
- You can setup exception tracker in `rescue block` to notify about errors

**Suggestions**:

- If you are using `Postgres` DB, then I recomment [`Que`](https://github.com/que-rb/que).
- Widely used queues are [`resque`](https://github.com/resque/resque) backed by `Redis`
- [Errbit](https://github.com/errbit/errbit) for Exception management and
- [Airbrake](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake) for tracking Exceptions

Answer (score 1):

If u are using Postgres, u can add this after import step to run after callbacks:

```
Book.import valid_books, validate: false

valid_books.each do |book|
  book.run_callbacks(:save) { true }
  book.run_callbacks(:create) { true }
end
```